# Angularjs $http and streaming data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I'm using angularjs's $http to make a call that returns streaming data, like this

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: config
}).success(function(responseData) {
        console.log(responseData);
}).error(function(data, status) {
              console.log("error:" + status)
});
```

I see the server is starting to send streaming data but neither the success nor the error callback is called. Can anyone shed some light as to what I'm going wrong here, trying to get streaming data?

Comment: Maybe server code just doesn't work properly? Have you ever tried to make this request as is from fiddler for example to see if the server returns something?

Comment: @Kate The server works well. I have other platform clients that are able to receive streaming data (Android and .Net). I'm trying to build a javascript client and I'm running into this situation.

Comment: Did you try debugging with Postman or cURL ? Also if you are using CDT, it's worth checking whether the request timed out from the Network tab, and update your issue description if so.

Comment: @MehdiChibouni Normal non-streaming methods work. It's just the streaming method that I'm having trouble with. The api is similar to twitter streaming api.

Comment: I don't see any streaming.  The success/error callbacks won't be called until the entire response gets to the browser and $http parses the json.

Answer (score 0):

The functions would be called after success or an error respectively, so they won't get called after the stream starts, but only after all the data is sent and the stream is closed (success) or if the stream fails to open (error).